# Where to put break statement or how to change my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, break

Hey I have break statement in code and it's just not working

I tried different positioning of break in code

```
number i in range(1,100):
    number=int(input('Give number '))
    if number== ' ':
        break
if number%2==0:
        print('number is even')
else:
        print('number is odd')
```

My teacher told me that the entry from the keyboard will end after the space is pushed

Comment: Was there supposed to be a `for` in there?

Comment: idk he said Write a program that figures out if the written number is even or odd. The input from keyboard will end if the space is clicked

Comment: I don't speak that.

Comment: yeah i was translating sr :DDD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you convert `number` into an integer *before* you compare it with `' '`. Make the comparison *before* you make the conversion. (Also, I changed your loop into a `while` loop, because it makes more sense if you want it to run until the input is a space.)

```
while True:
    number = input('Give number ')
    if number == ' ':
        break
    number = int(number)
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print('number is even')
    else:
        print('number is odd')
```

Comment: i dont know why but even after i tried this i click space and nothing happens it just writes space but i can still input number so its still running hmm

Comment: Press return after pressing space, the code above is waiting until a space is input instead of a number. To wait until the space bar is pressed you will need more.

Comment: Oh no sorry its working i just need to click enter after space wow im dumb thanks

Comment: @AFKManager If I answered your question, be sure to press the green checkmark on the left for future viewers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers